# serialize a text file into a protobuf message

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a serialized protobuf message that I can simply read and save in plain text in python with something like this:

```
import MyMessage
import sys

FilePath = sys.argv[1]

T = MyMessage.MyType()
f = open(FilePath, 'rb')
T.ParseFromString(f.read())
f.close()

print(T)
```

I can save this to a plain txt file and do what I want to do.

Now I need to do the inverse operation, i.e. reading the simple plain text file, already formatted in the right way, and save it as a protobuf message

```
import MyMessage
import sys

FilePath = sys.argv[1]

input = open("./input.txt", 'r')

T = MyMessage.MyType()
T.ParseFrom(inputText.readlines())
output.write(T.SerializeToString())

input.close()
output.close()
```

This fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyFile.py", line 13, in <module>
    T.ParseFromString(input.readlines())
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\message.py", line 199, in ParseFromString
    return self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 1142, in MergeFromString
    serialized = memoryview(serialized)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

I am not a python nor a protobuf expert, so I guess I am missing something trivial...
Any help?

Thanks :)

Comment: No one? :/
I didn't think it would have been a difficult task :(

Answer (score 2):

`print(x)` calls `str(x)`, which for protobufs uses the human-readable "text format" representation.

To read back from that format, you can use the `google.protobuf.text_format` module:

```
from google.protobuf import text_format

def parse_my_type(file_path):
  with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    return text_format.Parse(f.read(), MyMessage.MyType())
```